# xtable for conditional cell formatting not with special characters

Tags: r, latex, knitr, xtable, rnw

I'm apply solution from [*xtable for conditional cell formatting significant p-values of table*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24553963/1655567) to my data set; however, I can't use **`sanitize.text.function = function(x) x`** as per the suggested answer.

## Example

### Data set

The data set contains text columns that utilise **`_`** character, as in the example below:

```
dta <- data.frame(
    varA = c("this_and_that", "something_else", "def"),
    varB = c("other_thing", "something_different", "abc")
)
```

### `xtable`

When passed to [xtable](/questions/tagged/xtable) it using the syntax:

```
print.xtable(x = xtable(dta), 
             booktabs = TRUE,
             comment = FALSE,
             floating = TRUE,
             type = "latex",
             include.rownames = FALSE,
             NA.string = "NA",
             # Font and linespace size
             size = "\\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\\selectfont")
```

the code generates usable latex snippet:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begingroup\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
varA & varB \\ 
  \midrule
this\_and\_that & other\_thing \\ 
  something\_else & something\_different \\ 
  def & abc \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{table}
```

## Problem

I would like to apply **`\textbf{}`** to columns with word *something*. Following the answers discussed in the linked question this could be done via `ifelse` and `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x` as in the example below:

```
print.xtable(
    x = xtable(dta %>%
                   mutate_all(funs(
                       ifelse(grepl("something", .), paste0("\\textbf{", ., "}"), .)
                   ))),
    booktabs = TRUE,
    comment = FALSE,
    floating = TRUE,
    type = "latex",
    include.rownames = FALSE,
    NA.string = "NA",
    # Font and linespace size
    size = "\\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\\selectfont",
    sanitize.text.function = function(x) {
        x
    }
)
```

This will generate correct syntax with respect to the **`\\textbf{}`** but the **`_`** is not escaped due to : `sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x}`.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begingroup\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
varA & varB \\ 
  \midrule
this_and_that & other_thing \\ 
  \textbf{something_else} & \textbf{something_different} \\ 
  def & abc \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{table}
```

#### Removed `sanitize.text.function`

The code:

```
print.xtable(
    x = xtable(dta %>%
                   mutate_all(funs(
                       ifelse(grepl("something", .), paste0("\\textbf{", ., "}"), .)
                   ))),
    booktabs = TRUE,
    comment = FALSE,
    floating = TRUE,
    type = "latex",
    include.rownames = FALSE,
    NA.string = "NA",
    # Font and linespace size
    size = "\\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\\selectfont"
)
```

will generate awful mess as default sanitize behaviour will attempt to escape `\\textbf`

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begingroup\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
varA & varB \\ 
  \midrule
this\_and\_that & other\_thing \\ 
  $\backslash$textbf\{something\_else\} & $\backslash$textbf\{something\_different\} \\ 
  def & abc \\ 
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{table}
```

### Alternative approach / side point

Probably better approach would be to make use of the sanitize function:

```
print.xtable(
    x = xtable(dta),
    booktabs = TRUE,
    comment = FALSE,
    floating = TRUE,
    type = "latex",
    include.rownames = FALSE,
    NA.string = "NA",
    # Font and linespace size
    size = "\\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\\selectfont",
    sanitize.text.function = function(x) {
        ifelse(grepl("something", x), paste0("\\textbf{", x, "}"), x)
    }
)
```

## Summary

Is there other way of addressing this problem than greping all the special characters in my table and manually escaping them via custom sanitize function that would handle ***both*** elements `textbf{}` and `_` correctly?

---

## Working solution

Using:

```
  sanitize.text.function = function(x) {
    gsub(fixed = TRUE, pattern = "_", replacement = "\\_", 
         x = ifelse(grepl(pattern = "something", x = x), paste0("\\textbf{", x, "}"), x)
         )
  }
```

will work as it manually escapes **`_`**, ideally I would like to find a solution where I wouldn't have to manually espace each single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function in `Hmisc` which does the work : `latexTranslate`. Run it first and then apply the LATEX format commands.

```
library("Hmisc")
library("xtable")
dta <- data.frame(
    varA = c("this_and_that", "something_else", "def"),
    varB = c("other_thing", "something_different", "abc")
)
print.xtable(
    x = xtable(dta),
    file=paste0(getwd(),"/table/sanitize_test.tex"),
    booktabs = TRUE,
    comment = FALSE,
    floating = TRUE,
    type = "latex",
    include.rownames = FALSE,
    NA.string = "NA",
    # Font and linespace size
    size = "\\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\\selectfont",
    sanitize.text.function = function(x) {
      x <- latexTranslate(x)
      x <- ifelse(grepl("something", x), paste0("\\textbf{", x, "}"), x)
      return(x)
    }
)
```

[image]